# Electrical charger design with power factor correcttion

Tags: power, battery-charging, power-electronics, electrical

Design an Isolated battery charger with PFC( power factor correction), which will take input from 230V 3-phase supply. Calculate the value of inductor, transformer and capacitors used. Also, select appropriate switching devices and mention the components used.Required output :117 volt and 40 Amp.

What i have done is i have used the 3 phase rectifier and the caluculation of output rms is V=304.062v and supply current is =69.28A.

Now i am stuck here what should be my net step for smoothening and for PFC.

Answer (score 1):

> What i have done is i have used the 3 phase rectifier

I think you have fallen over at the first step. When you have a conventional 3 phase rectifier only two of the three phases supply current to the output at any one time and this means serious harmonic distortion. A quote from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmlubH3vDZAhWID8AKHX5nCcsQFghxMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unmannedsystemstechnology.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F12%2FTechnical-Paper-1-STEP-AC-DC-Conversion.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0YswbgxFqGWEiJwIaXwuUs): -

[image]

So, my advice is to use a topology that works with the 3 phases as individual circuits and apply PFC individually then combine the outputs to get the DC bus voltage like this: -

[image]

Picture taken from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjmlubH3vDZAhWID8AKHX5nCcsQFgg-MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpdfs.semanticscholar.org%2F57ad%2Ff42d361c64de8c9928ee425b8c706e13887c.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1zomMtLucVk-WN1Z-qwG7n)